# Android Support Library 22.0.1 not available to install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I want to install and use Android Support Library 22.0.1.

But when I open the SDK manager, I only see Android Support Library 23 listed which I have already downloaded and installed.

Is there any way to install Android Support Library 22.0.1 ?

[image]

Comment: If you have updated the library with new then the some previous functionalities are deprecated or have been upgraded.

Comment: Yes I had updated the library. Is there any way to revert back ?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, why down voting ? This is a genuine question.

Comment: You try to Google and download previous SDK version from any site and check your requirements. I will request you to use this api and then check whether your requirements are met. By the way I have not downvoted it.

Comment: OK. My comment was for whoeve downvoted. Thanks. I'm already googling it.

Answer (score 0):

You have this question tagged with [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio). In that case, you do not use the "Android Support Library". You use the "Android Repository". AFAIK, that will give you access to older versions of the various Android Support artifacts.

Comment: I need Android Support Library for com.android.support:support-v13 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7. I couldn't understand your answer properly.

Comment: @Ronn: "I need Android Support Library" -- Android Studio users get access to the support libraries from the Android Repository. This is covered in [the documentation for setting up the Android Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). For example, in step #3, "Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the Android Support Repository item instead [of installing the Android Support Library item]".

Comment: But anyhow I need Android Support Library 22.0.1 installed if I want to use 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.1' in my gradle file. How installing just Android Support Repository helps ?

Comment: @Ronn: I suggest that you read [the documentation that I linked to in my previous comment](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). The "Android Support Library" entry in the SDK Manager **is only for Eclipse**. According to the tag on your question, you are not using Eclipse, but instead are using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Android Studio and have Android Support Repository installed, your project will look into that repository for Android Support Library. However, not every version of Android Support Library is kept in that repository. The one you are looking for, 22.0.1, is a missing one. You can have a look at this directory in your sdk to see what versions are provided:

```
extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
```

That is to say, there is no easy way to install it, and it's by the decision of Google.

The solution is a compromise. You can use version 22.0.0 instead, which is included in Android Support Repository. To do so, find the app/build.gralde in your project directory, and change the line that refers to Android Support Library, make it look like this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

And do a granle sync again. I bet you won't notice any difference between 22.0.0 and 22.0.1.